# Gitlab login page is unreachable

Tags: nginx, configuration, login, ruby, gitlab

I've configured accidentally that *every logged out user will be redirected to `x` domain*, this was done by using the admin panel in the web interface.

Now, I only can access things via SSH like modifying `gitlab.rb`, I've even tried to access the database and see if there is something there that I can modify.

### How can I modify this configuration so I can login back again?

I'm trapped outside. (Is like closing the house with the keys in). What I want is simple, delete/modify the option that tells *nginx* to redirect me to that domain, but I cannot find it in `gitlab.rb`.

Comment: This settings should redirect you only on logout, not on every page. You should be able to get to the login page without any issues to change the setting back. If your browser is stuck in a redirect loop, clear its cache or try another browser.

Comment: On the computer that you are trying to log in from edit your `hosts` file (`/etc/hosts` on linux) , and add that domain with the server IP address. Set up that domain as an alias to the gitlab server. That way even after redirection you will be able to access this gitlab installation and you should be able to login and change those settings

Comment: @Sven I went to myserver.com/users/sigin instead of going to the home page (mydomain.com) and that solved the problem! Thanks, you saved the day. Make an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 0):

As @Sven stated, you can access to your login page without need of visiting the home screen, this is located at `whatever.domain.is/users/sigin`, because the configuration only redirects you when you're in the home page, in this case would be `whatever.domain.is/`.